# Finding median in array and returning true

Tags: java, arrays

I have to write a method that returns true if the number in an array is the median of the array. The median m is a median if the number of elements that are greater than m is the same as the number of elements less than m. Honestly, I'm completely stuck and not sure how to start it off.. would like to get tips only. Thanks!

```
public boolean isMedian(double[] sample, double m) {
    //just what i have so far
    boolean median;
    for(int i = 0; i < sample.length; i++) {

    }
}
```

Comment: count elements less than `m`, count elements greater than `m` the return `count1` == `count2`?

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the idea! I was overthinking things haha..

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public boolean isMedian(double[] sample, double m) {
    if ((sample.length % 2) == 0) return false;
    double[] lSample = new double[sample.length];
    System.arraycopy( sample, 0, lSample, 0, sample.length );
    Arrays.sort(lSample);
    double median = lSample[lSample.length/2]
    return median==m;
}
```

Comment: There are two problems with this solution: 1) It assumes that the array's length is odd. 2) It changes the inputted array, which is generally considered bad form. It would probably be cleaner to clone it before sorting.

Comment: much better! Two pointers - the mathematical definition of a median for an oddly-sized array is the element in position `(n+1)/2)`, not `n/2` as you have now. For an evenly-sized array the median is actually well defined - it's the average between the element in position `n/2` and `(n+1)/2`) - don't know if the OP wants this distinction or not though.